# Character joining and deleting in R

Tags: r, string, dataframe, datetime, string-substitution

I have a `data` and it has a column `yearmonthweek`. For example, `2012y05m1wk` means 1st week of May, 2012. Likewise, `2012y11m3wk` means 3rd week of November, 2012.
`data` looks like this:

```
data<-data.frame(yearmonthweek=c("2012y05m1wk","2012y05m2wk","2012y05m4wk","2012y11m3wk"))
```

Here, I want to change the expression as below:

```
data<-data.frame(yearmonthweek=c("2012051","2012052","2012054","2012113"))
```

How can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the letters from the column could work:

```
gsub('[a-z]','',data$yearmonthweek)
```